# Custom Log in with Facebook button using swift in iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I am trying to customize Facebook's FBSDKLoginButton (name of the class) in a sense that I want to possibly delete the FB logo, and change the background color, font and font color.

I was doing some research and unfortunately I was not able to find anything related to this topic.

Now my major question is, do I have to create a button and somehow connect the default FB functionality to it, or do I have to code it from scratch (which I don't think it would be the case). As of now, I have the default login button working by creating a button and just declaring it as a FBSDKLoginButton and it work perfectly. Also, I accessed it's properties after instantiating it to see if there was something I could change in viewDidLoad, such as text, background color, etc but I could not find anything.

I would greatly appreciate it if you could point me in the right direction on how to achieve this (tutorials, advice, etc.).

Thank you for reading my post and for your help in advance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try following options:

1) Create your own subclass of FBSDKLoginButton and override drawRect: to decorate your custom look and feel

2) An easy way would be - just use your own UIButton subclass.

Update:

for case 1 you can try overriding the following implementations -

```
    - (void)configureButton
{
  [self configureWithIcon:[[self class] defaultIcon]
                    title:nil
          backgroundColor:[[self class] defaultBackgroundColor]
         highlightedColor:[[self class] defaultHighlightedColor]];
}

- (void)configureWithIcon:(FBSDKIcon *)icon
                    title:(NSString *)title
          backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
         highlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor
{
  [self _configureWithIcon:icon
                     title:title
           backgroundColor:backgroundColor
          highlightedColor:highlightedColor
             selectedTitle:nil
              selectedIcon:nil
             selectedColor:nil
  selectedHighlightedColor:nil];
}

- (void)configureWithIcon:(FBSDKIcon *)icon
                    title:(NSString *)title
          backgroundColor:(UIColor *)backgroundColor
         highlightedColor:(UIColor *)highlightedColor
            selectedTitle:(NSString *)selectedTitle
             selectedIcon:(FBSDKIcon *)selectedIcon
            selectedColor:(UIColor *)selectedColor
 selectedHighlightedColor:(UIColor *)selectedHighlightedColor
{
  if (!selectedColor) {
    selectedColor = [self defaultSelectedColor];
  }
  if (!selectedHighlightedColor) {
    selectedHighlightedColor = highlightedColor;
  }
  [self _configureWithIcon:icon
                     title:title
           backgroundColor:backgroundColor
          highlightedColor:highlightedColor
             selectedTitle:selectedTitle
              selectedIcon:selectedIcon
             selectedColor:selectedColor
  selectedHighlightedColor:selectedHighlightedColor];
}

- (UIColor *)defaultBackgroundColor
{
  return [UIColor colorWithRed:65.0/255.0 green:93.0/255.0 blue:174.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (UIColor *)defaultDisabledColor
{
  return [UIColor colorWithRed:189.0/255.0 green:193.0/255.0 blue:201.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (UIColor *)defaultHighlightedColor
{
  return [UIColor colorWithRed:47.0/255.0 green:71.0/255.0 blue:122.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}

- (FBSDKIcon *)defaultIcon
{
  return [[FBSDKLogo alloc] init];
}

- (UIColor *)defaultSelectedColor
{
  return [UIColor colorWithRed:124.0/255.0 green:143.0/255.0 blue:200.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
}
```

Reference from : https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKButton.m

Comment: Got it... but what method/protocol does the Facebook Button call when pressed? I wanted to know which method to call so it can actually bring me to the login screen in either the facebook app or in the browser (what the actual facebook button does). Thank you for your help!

Comment: The method that gets called is _buttonPressed (reference: https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk/blob/master/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginKit/FBSDKLoginButton.m)

Comment: Sorry for not responding. Currently I do not have my laptop but as soon as I am able to get my hands on it, I will try it!

Comment: After a month (sorry) I tried it and it worked! Thanks!